# How to retrieve a value from mysql table compare from three tables using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

i want to retrieve a values from mysql table compare with three table using mysql query.

My Tables:

```
main_tbl:

id  name   email_id
--------------------   
1   test  test@gmail.com

Login_tbl:

login_id id  username
---------------------
1        1   anu
2        1   ahalya


sublogin_tbl:

login_id id  name   emailid 
------------------------
2       1   priya  priya@gmail.com
```

If i enter a username as "ahalya" first it checks with the login_id exists in sublogin_tbl   if value exists means it retrieve the values(name,emailid) from sublogin_tbl otherwise it returns the values from main_tbl.

Comment: And how to check with `main_tbl`? Did you missed `login_id` in `main_tbl`?

Comment: No i'm not use a login_id in main_tbl

Comment: then which column to compare in `main_tbl`? `id` itself?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you wanted exactly. Lets go through your need sentence by sentence

If i enter a username as "ahalya" first it checks with the login_id exists

```
'passing @username - ahalya

declare @intId as int;
Select @intId = (Select id from Login_tbl where username=@username )

if @intId >0 'login_id exists :retrieve the values(name,emailid) from sublogin_tbl
begin

   Select name,emailid from sublogin_tbl where id=@intId

end

else 'otherwise it returns the values from main_tbl.
begin

   'Here i don't know what exactly you want, we are searching by username and its only present in login table, put where in below as per your need !

    select * from main_tbl 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are looking for result in single query then this can be used (But only if `login_tbl` `id` is compared with `main_tbl` `id` - else you have to make some changes):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e84b2/10)

```
select name,emailid from sublogin_tbl where login_id = 
(select login_id from login_tbl where username='ahalya')
union
select name,email_id from main_tbl where id = 
(select id from login_tbl where username='ahalya')
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to create a stored procedure and inside the stored procedure put if else conditon to check if login id exists....

create procedure procedureName
(@userName nvarchar(50))
as
declare @counter int=0
set @counter=Select count(id) 
from sublogin_tbl
where name=@userName